# Mocha tests: avoid '../../' when requiring

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, require

My folder structure is:

```
/backend/services/service.js
/test/backend/services/service.js
```

In each service test, I use the following:

```
var service = require('../../../backend/services/service')
```

Is there a more elegant way of automatically requiring the file with the same path, only without the `test` folder? Maybe using `mocha.opts` somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a solution a little hacky that I use. I have a `/test/__bootstrap.test.js` file where I create a global `testRequire()` function that I only use for tests:

```
// Creation of a wrapper to avoid ../../../.. using require()
global.testRequire = function(name) {
  return require(path.join(__dirname, '..', name));
};
```

Then in `/test/backend/services/service.js` I use `testRequire()` instead of `require()`.

```
var service =  = testRequire('backend/services/service');
```